# Is there any way to mock an external call with more results in Foundry?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, foundry-forge, foundry-rs

I'm trying to write unit tests in Foundry and I've quite enjoyed the ability to mock external calls  using `function mockCall(address where, uint256 value, bytes calldata data, bytes calldata retdata) external`.

However, I can't figure out if there's any way to mock an external call that returns two different results when gets called twice in a function (similar to `sideEffect` in sinon).

Example:

```
function getDelta(address calculatorAddress) external returns (int256 delta) {
        ICalculator calculator = ICalculator(calculatorAddress);

        int256 preUpdateValue = calculator.getValue();

        calculator.update();

        int256 postUpdateValue = calculator.getValue();

        delta = postUpdateValue - preUpdateValue;
    }
}
```

If I use mockCall for `calculator.getValue()`, it will return the same result for both calls and I'll get 0. Hence, I'd like to be able to mock this call such that it returns different results.